# Ruby strftime: Day without leading zero, %e not working

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to format a date with a day without the leading zero

with %d it works fine, but with leading zero

```
date_time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
result: 04/01/11
```

I googled and found that I should use %e in stead of %d, but doing the following gives me an empty string.

```
date_time.strftime("%e/%m/%y")
result:
```

Does this have anything to do with the version of Ruby? I'm using v1.8.7 on a Windows machine.
And more important, is there another way to accomplish a day without leading zero (more convenient then gsub)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had problems before with strftime on Windows not supporting the exact same codes as on unix.

Also, I ran the following on mac os x:

```
> date_time.strftime("%e/%m/%y")
" 3/03/11"
```

As you can see, there is a space where the zero was. You still have to process the string *after* calling strftime.

I'd say, go with the safest bet, in this case %d, and call gsub/trim on it.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to drop the leading zero for month or day just add a minus sign in front of the format, like this:

```
Date.parse("2014/06/06").strftime("%Y/%-d/%-m")
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) Out of curiosity, where did you find this useful information?

Comment: been a long time since i went thru my remarks. a very long time. but to the question of how i new this. It works that way for UNIX date command. "date '+%-Y.%-m.%-d.%-H.%-M.%-S'"

Answer (score 9):

As an option:

```
date_time.strftime("#{date_time.day}/%m/%y")
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the `%e` still leaves a space in place of the 0. If you don't want the space I would just strip out the leading 0 like this.

```
> date_time.strftime("%d/%m/%y").gsub(/^0/, '')
"7/12/12"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
date_time.strftime("%d/%m/%y").gsub(/ 0(\d\D)/, ' \1')
```

Comment: The spaces before `0` and `\1` are wrong. Also this is seems like too raw and brute solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can use "-" flag to get rid of padding. [Source](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Example:

```
irb(main):002:0> Time.current.strftime("%-e %b %Y") 
=> "1 Jun 2022" 
irb(main):003:0> Time.current.strftime("%e %b %Y") 
=> " 1 Jun 2022"
irb(main):004:0> Time.current.strftime("%d %b %Y")
=> "01 Jun 2022"
irb(main):005:0> Time.current.strftime("%-d %b %Y")
=> "1 Jun 2022"
```